# Any quick ways to reset the change in docker container?

Tags: docker

I could use `docker diff` to inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem, like next:

```
$ docker diff inventory_web
C /var
C /var/cache
C /var/cache/nginx
A /var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp
A /var/cache/nginx/client_temp
A /var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp
A /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp
A /var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp
C /run
A /run/nginx.pid
C /etc
C /etc/nginx
C /etc/nginx/conf.d
C /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

But I wonder if any quick ways I could use to reset the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` to the default contents of the image which this container used?

Something like the operation in git: `git checkout -- default.conf`, could we use something like `docker reset` or `docker checkout` etc.?

Currently, I had to start a new container based on the same image, and copy the files in that container to my old container. But I think docker overlay file system certainly know what changed in the `rw` layer compared to the `ro` layer in image as it's layer based, otherwise, how `docker diff` could work?

Comment: Interesting question! You can do this manually by `docker cp`ing the file out of the running container at startup and then back when you want to do the reset. But you're right, the engine *should* be able to do that for you by simply discarding the r/w layer information for that file. Not sure if that actually exists as an API call.

Comment: I think the short answer to this is that it is not possible because it just not how `docker` is meant to be used: if you want to "reset" a container you should just delete it and start a new one from the image; if you want to keep persistent data from previous runs you should use volumes. So maybe you can add a bit more context on _why_ you want to do this and what you want to achieve. Maybe there is a better approach to this.

Comment: @acran In fact, no need this when for production. My scenario is: I'm working on a thirdparty project which code is in container. Sometimes I will change the code to trial, if ok will send PR. If not ok, I want to reset change & trial other solution, of course I could backup the old files with cp xxx xxx.bak, but sometime I forget this. YES, you may mean we need to change code under git, then send changes to staging container server to test. I knew the process, but I'm not the maintainer of the project, I just want to some changes, don't want a whole infrastructure here to assure my process...

Comment: @acran Anyway, my concern here is related to some quick task which directly handle things in container in development phase, not final production phase. In fact, I didn't see the usage of `docker cp` in final production container, we no need `docker cp` at all. From docker principle, all things should be in image or use bind mounts. Why need `docker cp?`, but it exists there, this is for development ease I think...

Answer (score 1):

Docker isn't SCM but you can use kinda a hack to copy the file from your base image.

```sh
docker cp $(docker create --rm <container_image>):/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf default.conf
docker cp default.conf <running_container_id>:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I did currently, but I wonder if I miss some simple usage...

Comment: That'll work, but I think OP is asking if the Docker engine can do that for you natively. I think conceptually it should be possible.

Comment: You can play with [overlayfs lower/diff directories](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/) and probably extract the file from there but it would be much harder. Container creation is much cheaper in this case if consider the efforts.

Comment: @max As far I know docker doesn't have a native approach for solving this task because `docker diff` has limited functionality.